# Prime factorization for big numbers

Tags: primes, prime-factoring

I am trying to find the complexity of a factorization for big numbers.
Which is the best algorithm and which is the complexity of finding a number's prime factors? Assume that the length of the number is n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best know algoritm for factoring integer larger than 100 digits is [General number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). It's complexity is explained on the page that the link links to.

Wikipedia has a nice article about other algoritms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Answer (score 0):

the complexity will be sqrt(n)log(n).But for n<=19^7 if you use sieve then after sieve it can be done in log(n).
You can see here -> http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7262