# Project Euler challenge 3

Tags: c

There's something wrong with my code and I don't know what. GCC compiles it without any warnings, but nothing gets outputted when it is run.

I'm just learning c (this is actually problem 3 of Euler. Find the largest prime factor of 600851475143).

What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int primeCheck(unsigned long input);

int main(){
  //goal: find largest prime factor of 600851475143
  unsigned long goal = 600851475143;
  for(unsigned long i = 600851475142; i > 0; i--){
    if(primeCheck(i) == 1 && goal%i == 0)
      printf("\n%lu\n\n", i);
  }

}

int primeCheck(unsigned long input){
  for(unsigned long i = 2; i < input; i++){
    if(input%i == 0)
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Isn't 600851475143 > 2^32-1?  I don't think you can store 600851475143 in an unsigned long.  If you an use an unsigned long long that might help.

Comment: 2^32-1 is 4,294,967,295. 600,851,475,143 is much larger.

Comment: Your program is most probably taking *too long* to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is most probably taking **too long** to execute. Try smaller numbers as Jerry hinted to validate your program.

You might want to look at this post: **[Prime factorization for big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564153/prime-factorization-for-big-numbers)** for better algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the correct-sized data structure (there's already enough discussion about that), your program is *definitely* taking too long to execute.

Note that unless 600851475143 itself is prime, the largest prime factor can't be more than 1/3 as big (as we can clearly see that 2 certainly isn't a factor). What that says is that with almost no math, I can already tell you that the if-statement in the first for loop is going to return false over 400 billion times, and you're doing a primality check **for each of them**. I don't care what algorithm you use; you can't make 400 billion primality checks fast. Even if you swapped it to take advantage of short-circuiting, you're doing 400 billion divisibility checks, which isn't efficient either.

Since this *is* Project Euler, I won't give it away, but I will give a hint: Suppose you knew some of the smaller prime factors. How might you use that to put an upper limit on how big the largest factor can be?

Answer (score 0):

OP's code will work with 64-bit `unsigned long`, but take too long.

Problems:

`primeCheck()` iterates up to `i < input` rather than up to `i <= isqrt(input)`.  Both will work, yet by only going up to the square root of `input`, the code will complete *much faster*.  Further testing is not needed.

Typically the remainder and quotient are calculated together, so by testing against the quotient, code gets "about the square root" for free - when does the divisor become less than the quotient?

```
int primeCheck(unsigned long input){
  unsigned long q = input;
  // for(unsigned long i = 2; i < input; i++){
  for(unsigned long i = 2; i <= q; i++){
    if(input%i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    q = input/i;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

The main loop starts looking for factors just 1 less than the goal.  This will work, yet the first possible factor is `isqrt(goal)`.  This is much faster

```
int main() {
  //goal: find largest prime factor of 600851475143
  unsigned long long goal = 600851475143;
  unsigned long goal_sqroot = (unsigned long) sqrt(goal);

  // In case  `double sqrt(double)` gave a too low `isqrt()` answer ...
  if (goal/goal_sqroot > goal_sqroot) goal_sqroot = goal/goal_sqroot;

  // for(unsigned long i = 600851475142; i > 0; i--){
  for (unsigned long long i = goal_sqroot; i > 1; i--) {
    if (primeCheck(i) == 1 && goal % i == 0)
      printf("%llu\n", i);
  }
}
```

`unsigned long` may only be 32-bit.  Use `unsigned long long` for larger numbers like 600851475143, a 40 bit number.

Output in < 2 seconds:

```
6857
1471
839
71
```

Other simplifications possible, this is a start.